# For a polynomial ring, is $f(x) \mapsto f(ax+b)$ an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I am a recent graduate studying a bit of algebra in my free time. I've stumbled across a problem that I haven't been able to write or find a proof for.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $a,b\in R$, where $a$ is a unit of $R$. If $R[x]$ is the polynomial ring with coefficients from $R$, then the mapping given by $f(x) \rightarrow f(ax+b)$ is an automorphism of $R[x]$.

I can see that ***if*** this is a homomorphism, then it's clearly an automorphism because it is invertible; the inverse map being $g(x) \rightarrow g(a^{-1}x-a^{-1}b)$. However, proving it's a homomorphism I've found difficult.

I'm actually not sure it actually is a homomorphism, but it feels like it should be if that makes sense. It feels like if I treated elements of $R[x]$ as functions rather than abstract polynomials it may be easier, but I'm really not sure.

I tried proving it was a homomorphism straight from the definition of addition and multiplication of polynomials, and that was very unpleasant, to say the least (nested sums from the binomial theorem). Also, as far as abstract algebra goes, I haven't really had any experience "plugging things into" polynomials (except for single elements regarding roots, etc.), so $f(ax+b)$ is kind of awkward at this point.

So I guess my question is "is there any slick/non-messy proof that $f(x) \rightarrow f(ax+b)$ is an automorphism of $R[x]$?" Am I missing a really obvious proof?

Thanks!

Comment: To prove it is a homomorphism, you want to show that if $h(x) = f(x) g(x)$, then $h(ax+b) = f(ax+b) g(ax+b)$ . But of course, it shouldn't matter what's inside the brackets, so long as it is the same for $h,f,g$, the identity should hold. In other words, if we write $y=ax+b$, it becomes obvious that $h(x) = f(x) g(x)$ implies $h(y) = f(y) g(y)$.

Comment: Note that you don't need $b$ to be a unit.

Comment: Prove a more general fact: if $g(x)$ is any fixed polynomial whatsoever, then $f(x) \mapsto f(g(x))$ is a ring homomorphism. You don't need to explicitly plug in or expand anything.

Comment: @jonan yep that's really obvious, thanks. I was way overthinking it lol

Comment: @user10354138 thanks. I knew that, but the post didn't say that. Edited

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yep, your generalization is very clear thanks to Jonan's enlightenment. Do you know under what conditions it would be an automorphism? Only of degree 1?

Comment: You are saying R is a commutative ring with unity only, If R is not a integral domain , this homomorphism is not an automorphism, by quick check of finding kernel!

Comment: An even more general (and *useful*) result is that if $S$ is a ring extension of $R$ and $\alpha\in S$, then there exists a unique homomorphism (called evaluation homomorphism) $\varphi:R[X]\to S$ which fixes $R$ and maps $X\mapsto \alpha$. Apply that to $S=R[X]$ and $\alpha=aX+b$.